# Force Firefox Title Bar to use Windows operating system theme colors

Tags: windows, firefox, themes

The latest Firefox version 89 update has lost respect for my theme choices on Windows 10 (20H2). Now title bars are all one color and I can no longer easily tell the difference between the active window and the inactive window.

Previously, the difference between active/inactive windows were easy to see:
[image: Previous Firefox showing correct title bar colors]

Now, Firefox 89 title bars for the active window and inactive window are the same:
[image: Firefox 89 with wrong title bar colors]

When I updated to Firefox 89, I picked the "System theme" which states: "Follow the operating system setting for buttons, menus, and windows." Unfortunately, it doesn't do that. I made sure that Windows has Settings> Personalization> Colors> "[Title bars and window borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oy0m.png)" is still checked. Other programs still behave appropriately.

I can put a regular title bar back on the window using the following:

about:config> "browser.tabs.drawInTitlebar = false"

This partially works and at least it follows the correct color scheme, but it leaves the tabs without colors. Since the setting that controls that describes drawing the tabs in the title bar it seems to me it should be following the title bar color scheme.

Turning off "proton" will apparently be disabled eventually, so making a userChrome.css as suggested in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1655055/897970) seems like a decent partial workaround. Unfortunately, each window has its own active/inactive tabs.

Here's how that userChrome.css defined title bar appears(ignore the black text, title bar color is the issue):
[image: New Firefox userChrome.css title bars]

As you can see, all tabs are colored the same, regardless of whether it's an active or inactive window.

So, how can I get Firefox to respect my operating system color choices?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Disabling Proton is no longer possible as of Firefox 91; and as of Firefox 92, there is no longer a built-in option to use the Windows accent color.

You can use a Firefox theme to add set colors to certain elements, but if you actually want to restore the ability to use the system theme color, you have to use a userChrome.css file.

[I wrote a file doing just that:](https://matthewminer.name/blog/how-to-get-windows-accent-colors-back-in-firefox-92)

```css
/* Show active colors on main menu bar */
#TabsToolbar,
#navigator-toolbox,
#tabs-newtab-button,
#titlebar toolbarbutton:not(:hover):not(:active),
#scrollbutton-up:not(:hover):not(:active),
#scrollbutton-down:not(:hover):not(:active),
.titlebar-color {
    background: AccentColor !important;
    color: AccentColorText;
    fill: AccentColorText !important;
}

#TabsToolbar:-moz-window-inactive,
#navigator-toolbox:-moz-window-inactive,
#tabs-newtab-button:-moz-window-inactive,
#titlebar toolbarbutton:not(:hover):not(:active):-moz-window-inactive,
#scrollbutton-up:not(:hover):not(:active):-moz-window-inactive,
#scrollbutton-down:not(:hover):not(:active):-moz-window-inactive,
.titlebar-color {
    background: unset !important;
    color: unset;
    fill: unset !important;
    transition: none !important;
}
```

Add that to your userChrome.css file, and you should have your colors back like they used to be. (At least until Mozilla breaks things again.)

Comment: Confirmed working in 92.0. Thank you so much. Make sure that you follow the instructions from [userchrome.org](https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html), especially setting `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets=true` in `about:config`, and restart after every CSS change.

Comment: Firefox 103 disturbed things again and the previous modification no longer works.

Comment: @Medinoc Thanks, I've updated everything now. For some reason Mozilla renamed the variables from `-moz-accent-color` and `-moz-accent-color-foreground` to `AccentColor` and `AccentColorText`.

Comment: This does not work with wallpaper slideshow + automatic accent color (win10). Best approximation I came up with is `background: color-mix(in lab, AccentColor 50%, #0d0d0d) !important;` but it's not a 100% match. For inactive `background: color-mix(in srgb, 75% grey, AccentColor) !important;` seems to be somewhat similar to chrome's inactive color.

Answer (score 13):

Right click on any button of the toolbar and select `Customize Toolbar...` from the context menu. The customization page opens. In the bottom left-hand corner, tick the checkbox `Title bar`.

This restores the behaviour of Firefox before version 89. If the checkbox is not ticked, Firefox tells your window manager to *not* add a title bar.

Comment: This is, unfortunately, the only solution I see. It makes you lose even more vertical space of course.

Comment: A little space can be regained by reverting the new wasteful tab strip to its previous design. Just set "browser.proton.enabled" to "false" in "about:config".

Comment: Why is this buried in "Customize Toolbar"?  It should be in Settings.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 7):

> **I cannot tell the difference between the active and the inactive window.**

They are tabs, not windows.

---

There are several way to change the colours.

1. Disable proton.

   It can be disabled by setting `browser.proton.enabled` to `false`.

   Mozilla do have a habit of disabling such options so it may not be available in Firefox 90.
2. You can modify `userChrome.css` to change these colours.

   Example:

   > ```
   > .tabbrowser-tab[selected] .tab-label {
   >   color: black !important;
   >   font-weight: bold !important;
   > }
   >
   > .tabbrowser-tab[selected] .tab-content {
   >   background: #fcb731 ! important;
   > }
   >
   > .tabbrowser-tab:not([selected]) .tab-content {
   >   background: #585060;
   > ```

   Another example:

   > ```
   >  /* Use color and shape to make the tabs look more like tabs */
   >  .tab-background {
   >    background: #585060;
   >    border-radius: 9px 9px 0 0 !important;
   >    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
   >    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) !important;
   >    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5) !important;
   >    border-bottom-width: 0px !important;
   >  }
   >
   >  /* Selected tabs I want a bright background with a dark foreground */
   >    .tabbrowser-tab[selected] .tab-background {
   >    background: #fcb731 !important;
   >  }
   >  .tabbrowser-tab[selected] .tab-label {
   >    color: black !important;
   >    font-weight: bold !important;
   >  }
   >  /* Draw a solid line underneath to make the selected tab look  connected* to the rest of the browser */
   >  #TabsToolbar {
   >    border-bottom: 2px solid #fcb731 !important;
   >  }
   >
   >  /* Hover over tabs */
   >  .tabbrowser-tab:hover .tab-background:not([selected]) {
   >    background: #686070 !important;
   >  }
   > ```
3. Install the [Firefox Color](https://color.firefox.com/?theme=XQAAAAIaAQAAAAAAAABBKYhm849SCia2CaaEGccwS-xMDPr9KfClsSTPZ6KR10egvAnvMJ8XO1z9fJ7dFCZ0g3XO4Y2xd-pWchUZjnhS7EY4GGZUn6vkTrAK5BHuikAvYffRTJxiezg8FCFlyR5oK4Lpmxevi6sCTAvDGmsGPN3RlDXhkUxJD2XrLFumvRPsPVUoD9yFWAen_UuK2mr2j46TIm5ypkm1Y9GifPPM2Sdoek5YBZgQ2BXCjB__lASdAA) extension:

   > Build, save and share beautiful Firefox themes.

   Go to Advanced Colors / Tab Selected setting.

**Source:** [Amit's Thoughts: Firefox 89 tab appearance](https://amitp.blogspot.com/2021/06/firefox-89-tab-appearance.html)

Comment: Someone will probably write a GreaseMonkey script if it does go away,

Comment: The examples are definitely windows, as they overlap. Yes, each contains multiple tabs, but that's not the issue being described in the question. Previously, a window's tab background would have a different color depending on whether the window was active or not. Now, the backgrounds of both windows are the exact same color. This is a problem not just when using multiple browser windows, but even when just using another program and Firefox at the same time. The top bar of a window (whether it's a titlebar or tab bar) has always been a different color, depending on which is active.

Comment: _"They are tabs, not windows."_ I'm confused, should this answer work for windows also or are they for tabs only? [sapanoia's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1657794/124408) definitely works for windows although it's ugly.

Comment: @SimoKivistö The CSS in this answer is effective for tabs. Firefox Color also does the same for tabs. However, [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1675508/897970) from Ullallulloo is able to recolor the whole title bar the way it used to be. I suggest trying it out to see if it's in line with your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

As said sapanoia, right click on any button of the toolbar and select `Customize Toolbar...` from the context menu. The customization page opens.

That said, on the bottom of the screen, clic on the "Theme" dropdown button and select the "system Theme".

Answer (score 0):

Did a search in about:config for draw to check status of

`browser.tabs.drawInTitlebar`

saw
`gfx.draw-color-bars`
Looks like if you toggle `true` (default is `false`) it returns to following system color for active/inactive title bars

Comment: I've toggled `gfx.draw-color-bars` between true and false, along with the `browser.tabs.drawInTitlebar` set true and false. I cannot tell the difference here between the settings for `gfx.draw-color-bars`. Can you explain in further detail or show us what you're seeing when you change the setting?